# How to implement User::findByAccessToken in yii2 using yii2-authclient

Tags: rest, authentication, yii2

Actualy, how to use yii2-authclient with yii2 rest api correctly?

I can't find best practice.

Any ideas?

Comment: In common case access_token implementation should be parallel to OAuth. Open authentication is the thing that used by Your server to get access to third-party services on behalf of user. Here is no need to store OAuth tokens on a client side. On the other hand access token mechanism is used by Your server to authenticate users without prompting their credentials. That's different tasks. What is your use case of `yii2-authclient` with RESTful API?

Comment: For example I have angular application, and yii2 rest api for it. And it should support login/password auth and via other services, like fb, google

Comment: That's what i'm talking about. You use OAuth to authenticate user (once per "session"). After authentication your API should generate access_token for further requests signing. No need to use OAuth token for every request only if your service isn't some kind of decorator for the third-party service (for example news reader). So acces_token implementation is competely up to you.

Comment: Ok, thnx, what is the best practice to implement this access_token?